# Best way to find distance between two geopoints(lats, longs) in node.js

Tags: node.js, geolocation, geospatial

Can anyone pls tell me what is the best way to find distance between two geopoints (lats, longs) in node.js . If there is any good node js library pls tell me. Also I dont want to find the straight line path i want to find the possible driving path between the locations.

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, according to the wording of your last, you need a wrapper to services like [Google Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix) or [The Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/). For example: [Google Distance Matrix API for Node.js](https://github.com/edwlook/node-google-distance):

Comment: Between google-distance-matrix  and google-distance can you pls suggest which is better and why.

Comment: If you enough distance and time in transit, it is sufficient `Google Distance Matrix API`. For detailed information about the route including the transfer point, the different modes of transport and so on, you should use `Google Directions API`.

Comment: Last link is broken, any other suggestions where can I find Google Distance Matrix for Node JS?

Answer (score 10):

You should try geopoint (https://www.npmjs.com/package/geopoint)
In order to measure the distance from point1 to point2 use

```
`
var GeoPoint = require('geopoint');
point1 = new GeoPoint(lat1, long1);
point2 = new GeoPoint(lat2, long2);
var distance = point1.distanceTo(point2, true)//output in kilometers
`
```

Comment: Actually I dont want to find the straight line path i want to find the possible driving path between the locations. Does it give shortest path or the possible path between the locations.

Comment: I 'm guessing shortest path. However through a quick search i found this module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-distance) which I believe may be what you're searching for, though I haven't yet tested it.